# Azure Budget creation from an Azure AD application context

Tags: azure

While trying to create azure budgets via Powreshell API ( New-AzureRmConsumptionBudget ).
When this is ran from Azure User context budget is created and alerts are coming. When ran from the context of a Azure AD Application budget is getting created but no alerts are coming.
Upon digging a bit I could see that there is an email address is mentioned at budget alert email. This email address intend is to contact to unsubscribe from alerts.
I'm not sure if that is the reason alerts are not coming.

Can some one help to clarify this

Answer (score 0):

As per [Azure blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enhancements-to-azure-budgets-api-supporting-resource-groups-and-usage-budgets/)

Calls to the budgets API enforce a user context. Due to this budgets won't be working as expected when created via powershell from an Azure AD application context.